# How to fetch all recordsets which are linked through that table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three tables, with these fields:

**classes**: class_id | name | grade

**classes_students**: class_id | student_id

**students**: student_id | name

Classes has a 1:n relationship with Students, so one class can have many students. I want to select all students of a particular class, where class_id is 5.

Could I just do something like this?

```
SELECT student.name FROM students student 
LEFT JOIN classes_students link 
    ON link.class_id = 5 
    AND link.student_id = student.student_id
```

I'm not sure about if I need the join here and if that has to be a "LEFT JOIN"? What I want is only a record set containing the student names.

Comment: The following statement you made is not exactly correct: "Classes has a **1:n** relationship with Students, so one class can have many students". In fact, the relationship between classes and students is **n:n** because one class can have many students **and** one student can have many classes. Hence the need for your `classes_students` table. If it were truly a **1:n** relationship, you wouldn't need the `classes_students` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT s.name
  FROM STUDENTS s
  JOIN CLASSES_STUDENTS cs ON cs.student_id = s.student_id
                          AND cs.class_id = 5
```

Alternately:

```
SELECT s.name
  FROM STUDENTS s
  JOIN CLASSES_STUDENTS cs ON cs.student_id = s.student_id
  JOIN CLASSES c ON c.class_id = cs.class_id
 WHERE c.class_id = 5
```

Because you want students only in a particular class, you'd use an INNER JOIN.  You'd use a LEFT JOIN if you wanted say a list of all the students, and then LEFT JOIN to `CLASSES_STUDENTS` to know if any are taking classes (because those that aren't would have null values in the `CLASSES_STUDENTS` columns).  I recommend [looking at this link for the breakdown of various JOINs and their impact on the data you'll get back](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    student.name 
FROM 
    students student 
INNER JOIN 
    classes_students link 
ON
    link.student_id = student.student_id
WHERE 
    link.class_id = 5
```

Your query should actually work fine if you just change your join to INNER, but i much prefer using a where clause to filter the results rather than including it in the JOIN criteria, i think it's clearer.